# Still having error in “The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.” in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've searched all posts and I find this same error they encountered. Most comments and feedback was successfully fixed, but when I do mine, it doesn't work,

I've already changed the `system/application/config/config.php` file from:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

to

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\-\=';
```

and the URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

when I set the value of `$config['enable_query_strings']` to `True`.

I have 404 "Page Not Found"

I use Codeigniter3 with PHP 5.6.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Wha characters you have in URL? Put an example.

Comment: localhost/project/book/search?q=ex

Comment: why you are using query string like this ?

Comment: why don't you pass your query string with just only slashes ? and pass the parameter in your route for this function ?

Comment: You removed index.php why don't you first try this solution having it and get back with the result. I think the 404 page not found is due the missing index.php in the uri